# How to use Angular 4 Emoji Picker?

Tags: angular5

I am new in Angular5 so I started with creating a demo project in which their will be a form where one input field is their in which user can select emojis.I follow this link [https://github.com/lbertenasco/ng-emoji-picker](http://github.com/lbertenasco/ng-emoji-picker) but the problem I am facing is that my inpute field doesnot show emoji selector.
      My **notification.module.ts code** is as shown below:

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

  import {EmojiPickerModule} from 'ng-emoji-picker';

  import { NotificationComponent } from 
  './components/notification.component';




 @NgModule({
declarations: [
    NotificationComponent
],
providers: [
],
imports: [


    EmojiPickerModule,
 ]
 })
  export class NotificationsModule { }
```

My **notification.component.html** code is shown below:

```
<div>
  <div fxLayout="row">
   <div fxFlex="80" fxFlexOffset="10">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title fxLayout="row">
        <div class="padding-top-10 padding-right-
     15">Notifications</div>
      </mat-card-title>
       <mat-card-content>
      <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap 
      novalidate [formGroup]="notificationForm" 
       (submit)="submitInst()">
     <emoji-input></emoji-input>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

**Problem:** When I run command ng serve I am just able to see the input field but no emoji picker.Can Anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing emoji-input in notification.component.html file.
Add this for emoji-input

`<emoji-input [(model)]="bindedVariable" [textArea]="{cols: 40, rows: 5 [onEnter]="onEnterFunction" [popupAnchor]="'bottom' (setPopupAction)="setPopupAction($event)">
</emoji-input>`

And add the below in the **notification.component.ts** file inside the export class.

```
 public openPopup: Function;

setPopupAction(fn: any) {
    this.openPopup = fn;
}
```